# Keep query string unencoded in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to manually concatenate query parameters into a string and bind the value to `routerLink` attribute. this is the .ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {        
    this.href = "data/?project="+this.number+"&item="+this.number2;
}
```

I than bind it in HTML:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#" [routerLink]="[href]">LINK HERE</a>
```

the issue is that Angular enocdes `=`, `?` `&` signs into `%3F`, `%3D` and `%26` and displays that in the link. What should I do to keep `=, ?` and `&` unencoded?

Comment: Try using `preserveQueryParams` attribute on `<a`

Answer (score 1):

The answer I went with is to use `[queryParams]` next to `[routerLink]`.

Example:

```
<a [routerLink]="[href]" [queryParams]="{project: projectNumber}">Details</a>
```